# Retrofit error URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit

I have this function

```
      @GET("/users?filters[0][field]={param}&filters[0][operator]=equals&filters[0][value]={value}")
UserDto retrieveUsersByFilters(@Path("param") String nameFilter, @Path("value") String value);
```

I try to call it like this :

```
   UserDto currentUser = interfaceUser.retrieveUsersByFilters(User.LOGIN, login);
```

But i have error :

retrofit.RetrofitError: InterfaceUser.retrieveUsersByFilters: URL query string "filters[0][field]={param}&filters[0][operator]=equals&filters[0][value]={value}" must not have replace block.

I already test url on firefox and it work fine.

Thank's for your responses

Edit

Solution:

```
          @GET("/users?filters[0][operator]=equals")
          UserDto retrieveUsersByFilters(
          @Query("filters[0][field]") String nameFilter,
          @Query("filters[0][value]") String value);
```

Comment: Very complicated url in this question - suggest you read the doc
http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Query.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Query params have their own annotation which automatically appends to the URL.

```
@GET("/users?filters[0][operator]=equals")
UserDto retrieveUsersByFilters(
    @Query("filters[0][field]") String nameFilter,
    @Query("filters[0][value]") String value);
```

You can read more about `@Query` on [its Javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Query.html)

Comment: Those dead links.. :(

Comment: Link is not working anymore for the Javadoc :-/. Is there any other link?

Answer (score 5):

```
 URL="/api-mobile_prateek2.php?method=getProductById&pid="


 @GET("/api-mobile_prateek2.php?method=getProductById")
    Call<Product> responseproduct(@Query("pid") String pid);
```

dont put the **pid** in the @GET,, Retrofit automatically fix the url, using @Query

Comment: A service provider requires a json definition AT THE END of a HTTP GET, like below, to avoid the XML default. How is this implemented using retrofit2? 

http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?channelid=132&format=json

Answer (score 1):

> From the [JavaDoc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Query.html):

**Example 1:**

```
@GET("/friends")
 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query("page") int page);
```

Calling with foo.friends(1) yields /friends?page=1.
Example with null:

---

**Example 2:**

```
@GET("/friends")
 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query("group") String group);
```

Calling with foo.friends(null) yields /friends.
Array/Varargs Example:

---

**Example 3:**

```
@GET("/friends")
 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query("group") String... groups);
```

Calling with foo.friends("coworker", "bowling") yields /friends?group=coworker&group=bowling.
Parameter names and values are URL encoded by default. Specify encoded=true to change this behavior.

---

**Example 4:**

```
@GET("/friends")
 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query(value="group", encoded=true) String group);
```

Calling with foo.friends("foo+bar")) yields /friends?group=foo+bar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your values directly in the path, but prefer in the method signature.
Not completely sure, but try something like this :

```
@GET("/users?filters[0][operator]=equals")
UserDto retrieveUsersByFilters(@Path("filters[0][field]") String nameFilter, @Path("filters[0][value]") String value);
```

Comment: In your  method, when you use a @Path argument it will add this parameter to your URL
For exemple, the url /login?usr=john will be a result of
@GET("/login")
void myMethod(@Path("usr") String usr)
with 'usr' arg set to 'john' when calling the method

Comment: i try your solution but i have this error :
retrofit.RetrofitError: InterfaceUser.retrieveUsersByFilters: @Path parameter name must match \{([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\}. Found: filters[0][field] (parameter #1)