# Make Get request with using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, yandex-maps

I want to make Request to Yandex using retrofit

Path to make reuqest is http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=latitude%2Clongitude

now I have this:

```
@GET("/?format=json&geocode={geocode}")
Call<YandexResponse> getGeoCollection(@Path("geocode") String geocode);
```

when I call it i am getting this exception:

URL query string "format=json&geocode={geocode}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

How to correctly make request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit error URL query string must not have replace block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610243/retrofit-error-url-query-string-must-not-have-replace-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("/")
Call<YandexResponse> getGeoCollection(@Query("geocode") String geocode, @Query("format") String format);
```

Then you should manually put format in function invocation:

```
webService.getGeoCollection("address", "json");
```